# setup qtcreator kit for cross compiling (mxe)

Tags: qt, qt-creator, cross-compiling, mxe

I'm trying setup an environment to cross-compile my projects from ubuntu to windows.
Looking around I managed to compile qt through mxe, now the problem is I can't get it to work inside qtcreator.
Being specific, I added in QtVersion tab

```
/home/user_name/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/bin/qmake
```

which has the following attributes

```
Name: Qt 5.4.0 (qt5)
ABI: x86-windows-unknown-pe-32bit
Source: /home/snake91/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5
mkspec: win32-g++
qmake: /home/snake91/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/bin/qmake
Version: 5.4.0
QMAKE_SPEC linux-g++
QMAKE_VERSION 3.0
QMAKE_XSPEC win32-g++
QT_HOST_BINS /home/snake91/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/bin
QT_HOST_DATA /home/snake91/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5
QT_HOST_LIBS /home/snake91/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib
QT_HOST_PREFIX /home/snake91/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5
QT_INSTALL_ARCHDATA /home/snake91/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5
QT_INSTALL_BINS /home/snake91/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/bin
QT_INSTALL_CONFIGURATION /home/snake91/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/etc/xdg
QT_INSTALL_DATA /home/snake91/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5
QT_INSTALL_DEMOS /home/snake91/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/examples
QT_INSTALL_DOCS /home/snake91/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/doc
QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES /home/snake91/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/examples
QT_INSTALL_HEADERS /home/snake91/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/include
QT_INSTALL_IMPORTS /home/snake91/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/imports
QT_INSTALL_LIBEXECS /home/snake91/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/bin
QT_INSTALL_LIBS /home/snake91/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib
QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS /home/snake91/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/plugins
QT_INSTALL_PREFIX /home/snake91/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5
QT_INSTALL_QML /home/snake91/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/qml
QT_INSTALL_TESTS /home/snake91/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/tests
QT_INSTALL_TRANSLATIONS /home/snake91/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/translations
QT_SYSROOT
QT_VERSION 5.4.0
```

I tried to add every file in ../mxe/usr/bin directory as compiler but I always receive the same msg: "The compiler xxxxxx cannot produce code for this QT version"
Note that I simply gave make qt5, without arguments...

ps of course I set the "new" qt version also in the kit tab

Answer (score 2):

Open QtCreator and go to `Tools->Options->Build&Run->Compilers` menu then change the default ABI value of installed appropriate compiler to what you see in the spec output of the toolchain: *x86-unknown-unknown-32bit* to *x86-**windows**-unknown-**pe**-32bit*.

Comment: Your answer is a bit dense IMHO.

Comment: You must specify the correct [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) version when you add a new toolchain to Qt Creator as you can see at [step 5 of _Adding Compilers_ document](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-tool-chains.html). In the above question, the reason of the error is specifying the wrong value for ABI version.